# URL sendo gerada incorretamente

Tags: wordpress, url, caracteres

Estou com um problema onde  as imagens do meu site estão sendo puxadas com caracteres especiais e torna algumas imagens inacessíveis.

Por exemplo:
Url certa:
eusou.fit/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/deltoides-quadriséries.jpg

Url gerada:
eusou.fit/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/deltoides-quadrisĆ©ries.jpg

Como resolver?

Administro meu site no wordpress

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/eusou.fit/pESk0YSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu site não tem a meta tag indicando o charset. Tente incluir isso:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

dentro da tag `<head>` e veja se resolve.

Comment: Bingo! Exatamente esse o problema. 

Adicionei manualmente como você falou pelo e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pelo toque Ricardo, salvou a pátria.

Comment: Antes eu acho que essa configuração era feita por algum plugin ou no .htaccess (fiz modificações nos dois itens hoje, por isso não sei qual foi).

Comment: massa @HenriquePires. Se puder, marque essa resposta como aceita pra ficar claro pra quem pesquisar depois.